# How to map values in a range of lowest double to max double to a new range without overflow?

Tags: c++, math, c++11, vector

I am trying to figure out a general function that would take any value in a range from std::numeric_limits::lowest() to std::numeric_limits::max() and map it to another range, for example -1000 to 1000?

I am stuck on the fact that there is no unsigned double, nor do I have access to quadruple precision so I keep running into the issue of overflow, eg: std::numeric_limits::max() - std::numeric_limits::lowest() //overflow

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: why do you need to compute `max - lowest` ? Computing `max/3` - `lowest/3` should be ok, or in fact any constant greater than 2. This will allow you to uniformly distribute the numbers in `[-a, a]` for any `a`.

Comment: oh my, I was way over thinking this problem.

Comment: Yep, that seems to work if I just scale all my values by the constant. Thanks.

Comment: yes of course, but this is not a problem since you can scale them back

Comment: Usually lowest == -max, so you can multiply by 1000/max to achieve your result.